# How do I use ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}= in udev rule?

Tags: linux, systemd, udev

I want to set up a `docked.target` in my user level systemd. The idea is to run some services to configure my external displays.

I currently have this as my rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="17ef", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="100a", SYMLINK+="tp_mini_dock", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="docked.target"
```

The rule gets detected just fine (I can see `dev-tp_mini_dock.device` when I'm docked).

I then have this in `~/.config/systemd/user/docked.target` (also tried `/etc/systemd/user` with no luck):

```
[Unit]
Description=Docked to ThinkPad Mini Dock
BindTo=dev-tp_mini_dock.device
```

But this does not start when I dock. However, if I manually start `docked.target` while docked, it stops as expected when I undock.

However, if I use `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="docked.target"` and put the file in `/etc/systemd/system/docked.target`, the target starts as expected when I dock. The problem then, is that my user level instance doesn't know about system-level services/targets.

Any thoughts? I've seen a few other questions around the net, and one almost exactly like mine: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1600019

Comment: The problem might be that you used `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="docked.target"` instead of `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="docked.target"`.

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.device.html

Answer (score 4):

Although I still don't know how `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}` works, I managed to get my specific problem solved after reading [this blog](http://blog.tjll.net/systemd-for-device-activation-and-media-archiving/).

It turns out that I can install targets as a dependency on devices. I changed my unit file `~/.config/systemd/user/docked.target` to:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docked to ThinkPad Mini Dock
BindsTo=dev-tp_mini_dock.device
After=dev-tp_mini_dock.device

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-tp_mini_dock.device
```

and my udev rule to:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="17ef", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="100a", SYMLINK+="tp_mini_dock", TAG+="systemd"
```

and then enable it with `systemctl --user enable docked.target`.

Now, when I dock it, the udev rule creates the systemd device, which in turn starts up the target. Then the `BindsTo` option makes sure that when the device disappears (gets unplugged) the target gets stopped.

I had to do some nonsensical magic to get this to work when I login with the dock already plugged in. One would imagine that simply adding `default.target` to `WantedBy` and `After` would be enough... I'll add a link to a blog after I write it.

Comment: What was your solution to firing the service on login while docked?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember, sorry I never got around to writing the blog post  :( IIRC it was something similar to https://aiguofer.medium.com/systemd-sleep-target-for-user-level-10eb003b3bfd (using dbus monitors), but I could be totally off base there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try replacing `SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS` with `MANAGER_USER_WANTS`. I'm not 100% sure about this name change, but at least in `systemd-226` there is no mention of `SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS` in the sources any more and it seems to be replaced by `MANAGER_USER_WANTS`. At least it worked for me for the similar case.

Answer (score 1):

Man...  That problem made me sick as well, what a bug!

In my case, I wanted to listen to HDMI (monitor hotplug) events, and I found a trick how to work around this problem.  I thought to myself, well, if this `udev` somehow knows that it started a service with this or that name and refuses to do it again, then let's make it believe that it starts a new service each time.  All eyes on the corresponding `udev` event:

```
UDEV  [19214.534185] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0 (drm)
ACTION=change
DEVLINKS=/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:01:00.0-card
DEVNAME=/dev/dri/card0
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0
DEVTYPE=drm_minor
HOTPLUG=1
ID_FOR_SEAT=drm-pci-0000_01_00_0
ID_PATH=pci-0000:01:00.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_01_00_0
MAJOR=226
MINOR=0
SEQNUM=3364
SUBSYSTEM=drm
USEC_INITIALIZED=3280572
```

and notice the `SEQNUM`.  It's changing on every new event and that's exactly what we want:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{HOTPLUG}=="1", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}+="monitor-hotplug@$env{SEQNUM}.service", TAG+="systemd"
```

Works like a charm even for `~/.config/systemd/user/monitor-hotplug@.service`.  Hopefully, your events also have `SEQNUM` or something similar.